# Return URL from Locator streaming of Azure Media Service into Controller in C#

Tags: c#, url, video, azure-media-services

I have encoded my video in azure media services and I want to request the url into my controller (C#). 
I check the microsoft site to get the url from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/operations/locator#list_locators

And here is the code:

```
GET https://<accountname>.restv2. 
<location>.media.azure.net/api/Locators('nb:lid:UUID:627cbafb-3d81-4623- 
97c2-2194282b6d16') HTTP/1.1  
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose  
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose  
DataServiceVersion: 3.0  
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0  
x-ms-version: 2.11  
Authorization: Bearer http%3a%2f%2fschemas.xmlsoap.~~~~
Host: media.windows.net
```

anyone know how to use this code into my C# controller so I can return the video's url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple issues I noticed:

1) your Authorization: Bearer token looks like the old ACS version - make sure that you are using AAD authentication and JWT tokens. See the docs for AAD authentication support in the REST API.

2) To get a Locator, It may be handy to look at the REST API Postman Collection that I created up here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/postman-collection

That should show you how to create and Get a locator for Streaming.

There is also an article that covers basic Streaming with the REST API here -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-rest-deliver-streaming-content

NOTE: That documentation page still has the older style Authorization header. Don't copy that header.  You will need to use an Auth Header like this:

Authorization: Bearer {{ENCODED JWT TOKEN}}

Full walkthrough on how to get that JWT Token for AAD is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-rest-connect-with-aad  but you can also use my Postman collection as a nice quickstart.

Comment: Also just noticed you said C# - Why not use the .NET SDK for Media Services?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. What is the advantage of .net sdk ?

Comment: Just easier if you are .NET user. It has some convenience features.  Going forward, in v3, it will just be a wrapper of the REST API... so no real advantage other than you don't have to build your own C# wrapper